# Why does np.split create a copy when passing into an existing array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python and trying to understand the behaviour of views and copies, so apologies if this is an obvious question! In the example below, I use `np.split()` to split an array `x`. When I pass np.split into a new object (either `x1`, a list of 3 1D arrays or `x2, x3, x4`, three separate 1D arrays) the objects are views of `x`, as expected:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1, 10)                        # create an array of length 9

x1 = np.split(x, (3,6))                     # split array into 1 new object (list of arrays)
print(x1[0].base)                           # each array in list is a view

x2, x3, x4 = np.split(x, (3, 6))            # split array into 3 new objects
print(x2.base)                              # these objects are views
```

However if I create an empty (3,3) array `x5` and pass np.split into each row of this array (I know this is a silly thing to do, I'm just trying to figure out how splitting works), a copy is created:

```
x5 = np.empty((3,3), dtype = np.int32)      # create an uninitialised array
x5[0], x5[1], x5[2] = np.split(x, (3, 6))   # split x into each row of x5
print(x5.base)                              # this object is a COPY
```

I thought perhaps that the slicing of x5 was causing a copy to be made, but if I slice `x2, x3, x4` they are still views:

```
x2[:], x3[:], x4[:] = np.split(x, (3, 6))   # split array into 3 existing objects using indexing
print(x2.base)                              # these objects are views
```

I haven't managed to find an explanation for this in any explanations of views and copies or np.split - what am I missing?

Comment: I deleted my answer, since you observation was correct that it is in fact a copy/not a view on the base array. To check you can do `x2.base is x # returns True` and `x5[0].base is x # returns False`.

Comment: The copying does not happen as part of `np.split` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) but through the assignment

Comment: `x5` has its own data buffer (base).  Copying values to it doesn't change that.  `np.hstack((x2,x3,x4))` also makes a copy, even though it looks like `x`

Comment: `split` is doing `[x[:3], x[3:6], x[6:]]`, returning a list of slices.  `x5[:,:] = x.reshape(3,3)` would also copy values from `x` to `x5`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for this. Is it then a general rule that when a transformation like `split` is applied and then assigned into a subset of a new object, that the elements are copied rather than creating a view? `x6[0:3], x6[3:6], x6[6:9] = np.split(x, (3, 6))` (where x6 is an empty array of length 9) also creates a copy.

Comment: The description of `x5` as "uninitialized" may be confusing you.  It is a regular array with its own data (base).  The values just haven't been set to 0 as `np.zeros` would. `x5[0:3] = x[3:6]` copies 3 values from `x` to `x5`.  `x2[:] = x[3:6]` also copies values, but `x2` is a view of `x`, so you end up modifying `x`, its base.  In general any `y[...]=z[...]` (where `...` just means any indexing), will copy values from `z` to `y`.  It does not make `y` a `view` of `z` (that is, `z` will not be its base - unless that was the case before the assignment).

Comment: `x5` is *not a copy*, you created an entirely new array here: `x5 = np.empty((3,3), dtype = np.int32)` with it's own internal buffer, as you would expect any time you create an array with these contructors. This has nothing to do with split.

Comment: @LucyWheeler they are *entirely separate array objects from the get go*. You *explicitly created another array object*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is only loosely related to `split`. `numpy` arrays have a *single* "rectangular block" of data behind them, they can't refer to multiple independent allocations. That block might be viewed in weird ways (by striding, masking, transposing, etc.) so the individual entries are not necessarily *contiguous*, but they're all backed by one, and only one, contiguous bulk allocation.

That allocation can be unique to the array, or a view of some other array, but a given array object doesn't change between owning storage and viewing storage, it's one or the other. The *name* the array is bound to can be reassigned, but all names can be reassigned (`x = 1` doesn't make `x` always that specific `int`, or even always *some* `int`; `x = ANYTHING` later on would rebind it to a completely new object of arbitrary type, ignoring what it used to be).

Knowing this makes it clear that it's *impossible* to reassign *part* of an array to be a view of some other array. So to explain your various observations:

```
x2, x3, x4 = np.split(x, (3, 6))            # split array into 3 new objects
print(x2.base)                              # these objects are views
```

As you noted, this is the expected behavior. `np.split` returned a `list` containing three new arrays of view type, each backed by part of `x`.

```
x5 = np.empty((3,3), dtype = np.int32)      # create an uninitialised array
x5[0], x5[1], x5[2] = np.split(x, (3, 6))   # split x into each row of x5
print(x5.base)                              # this object is a COPY
```

Line 1 here creates a new array of *owning* type. Even if it were possible to replace the underlying storage buffer with a different one (either to own a new buffer, or to view some other array's buffer), and I won't swear this is impossible (I haven't explored `numpy` enough to say for sure), it's definitely impossible to make it a mix of owning and viewing. Consider the simpler code:

```
x5[0] = x[:3]
```

If that code worked, and *didn't* copy the data from the view of `x` to the view of `x5[0]`, then somehow, `x5[0]` would need to be a view of `x`, while the rest of `x5`'s data would be owned. What happens to the three elements in the buffer that backed `x5[0]`? You might think "But I'm replacing all of them at once", but you're actually not. `x5[0], x5[1], x5[2] = np.split(x, (3, 6))` is effectively equivalent to `__unnamedtemp = [x[:3], x[3:6], x[6:]]`, followed by `x5[0] = __unnamedtemp[0]`, then `x5[1] = __unnamedtemp[1]`, then `x5[2] = __unnamedtemp[2]`. The unpacking work *must* be done piecemeal (unpacking is a general feature of Python that `numpy` can't hook), so even if, in theory, the end result could leave `x5` viewing `x`, in practice it can't, even `numpy` wanted to, because the intermediate stages are illegal state.

By comparison,

```
x2[:], x3[:], x4[:] = np.split(x, (3, 6))   # split array into 3 existing objects using indexing
print(x2.base)
```

"works" only because `x2`, `x3` and `x4` were *already* views of `x`. But copies are still being made; `x2` was already a view of `x[:3]`, and you just told `numpy` to copy the contents of `x[:3]` to `x2[:]`. Under-the-hood, once `x2.__setitem__` is invoked with an argument of the complete slice and another `numpy` view, and `numpy` has enough information and control, it *might* notice that the raw memory addresses are the same and avoid the copy, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if it just blindly copied the data from every address in the view to itself.

You'd be able to see that it is not making new views if you hadn't reused `x2` through `x4`:

```
x2, x3, x4 = np.arange(1, 4), np.arange(1, 4), np.arange(1, 4)  # Three owning arrays
x2[:], x3[:], x4[:] = np.split(x, (3, 6))  # Makes three views, then copies from views to owned buffers
print(x2.base)  # Does not have a base, because it's still not a view
```

The short version here is that:

1. **Assignment of *anything* to plain names** (no indexing/slicing) **will rebind that name, without copying data** (ignoring whatever used to be bound to that name); if you assigned a viewing array, it's now a view, if you assigned an owning array, it's now an owning array.
2. **Assignment of *either* views or owning arrays to an index or slice of an existing array** (view or owning) **will copy the data from one array to the other** (copying into the viewed buffer if applicable)

This is how it works for all types in Python. The only thing unusual about the `numpy` case is that you can *make* views; the built-in Python sequences (save the weird `memoryview` that's lightly `numpy`-like) don't have a concept of views, so the slices on the right-hand side of an equals sign will be shallow copies, but assignment *to* slices on the left-hand side will still copy (whether or not the right-hand side is a view or copy).

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation! I was confused as to why splitting into an existing object created a view but your point that this action 'overwrites' the entire object makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In an ipython session, make your `x`, and splits

```
In [23]: x=np.arange(1,10);x
Out[23]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [24]: x2,x3,x4 = np.split(x,(3,6))
```

Examine one:

```
In [25]: x2
Out[25]: array([1, 2, 3])    
In [26]: x2.base
Out[26]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I find the following display of array information helpful.  The 'data' field "points" to the underlying databuffer.  It can't be used in code, but the number is a useful identifier of where the values are actually stored.

```
In [28]: x.__array_interface__
Out[28]: 
{'data': (2389644026224, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (9,),
 'version': 3}
```

`x2` has the same 'data' value:

```
In [29]: x2.__array_interface__['data']
Out[29]: (2389644026224, False)
```

`x3` and `x4` will have slightly different values, pointing to bytes further in the buffer (e.g. `2389644026236` for `x3`, 3*4 further on).

`x5` is a new array with its own databuffer:

```
In [30]: x5 = np.empty((3,3),int);x5
Out[30]: 
array([[4128860, 6029375, 3801155],
       [5570652, 6619251, 7536754],
       [7340124, 7667809,     108]])    
In [31]: x5.__array_interface__['data']
Out[31]: (2389645593712, False)
```

Assigning values to `x5` copies those values, but doesn't change its databuffer location:

```
In [32]: x5[:] = x2,x3,x4    
In [33]: x5
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])    
In [34]: x5.__array_interface__['data']
Out[34]: (2389645593712, False)
```

`x` and `x5` remain their own 'bases':

```
In [35]: x.base, x5.base
Out[35]: (None, None)
```

We could index another 3 values from `x` and assign them to the `x2` view:

```
In [38]: x[-2:-5:-1]
Out[38]: array([8, 7, 6])    
In [39]: x2[:]=x[-2:-5:-1]      # not x2=x[...]
```

`x2` will be changed, but so will its base:

```
In [40]: x2.base
Out[40]: array([8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])    
In [41]: x
Out[41]: array([8, 7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

The assignment in [39] is just as "expensive" (time wise) as copying 3 values to `x5`.  It's still copying.  But the difference lies in where the values are copied too.